# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I m trying to connect to a wcf service hosted with https

I passed the right Credentials to the server

```
enter code here   var channel = new ConfigurationChannelFactory<C>(serviceConfigName, pluginConfig, new EndpointAddress(Url));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
        {
            channel.Credentials.UserName.UserName = UserName;
            channel.Credentials.UserName.Password = Password;
            channel.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
        }
        return channel;
```

and I used the below configuration

```html
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint
          name="ms_basic_http"
          address="http://localhost"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="defaultBasicHttpsBinding"
          contract="ICONTRACT" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding >
        <binding name="defaultBasicHttpsBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" realm="BS"   />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"  />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

but getting the below response from the server

The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="BS'

Answer (score 0):

Change the security config to:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding >
    <binding name="defaultBasicHttpsBinding">
      <security mode="Transport"> //or none
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: it get back to The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="BS'

Comment: did you added this two line also <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />

Comment: yes , but it dint work I recieved request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.  but if I Turn lientCredentialType="Basic" it change to got The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="BS"'.

Comment: So try to use <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>

Comment: same issue , the server require Basic Authentification

Answer (score 0):

when I changed the  config to be

```html
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint
          name="ms_basic_http"
          address="http://localhost"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="defaultBasicHttpsBinding"
          contract="contract" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding >
        <binding name="defaultBasicHttpsBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="BS" />
            
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I got 
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="BS"'.